# How to call a method in one object from another object in the same structure

Tags: c++, methods, class-design

I have the following situation:

```
class B
{
    public:
        void methodInB();
};

class C
{
    public:
        void methodInC();
};

class A
{
    public: 
        void methodInA();
    private:
        B objB;
        C objC;
};

void A::methodInA()
{
    objB.methodInB();
}

int main()
{
    A objA;
    objA.methodInA();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to be able to call `C::methodInC()` from within `B::methodInB()`, but I'm not sure what the way to go about it would be (not without messing with globals).

My first idea was to add a `C* pC` pointer as a member of `B`, and then from `methodInB()` call it as `pC->methodInC`. This would require I set the pointer from within `A` before using the method (possibly in `A`'s constructor). My problem is I may need to call other objects from within `B` if I add a `D` and `E` objects, and I don't want to fill the class definition with pointers.

Is there some other way of doing this? An implicit reference to the object the object belongs to? Kind of like `this` but for the parent? So I could at least do `parent->objC->methodInC()`?

Comment: Your `objB` and `objC` don't know of each other. There's no such thing as generically "knowing who you belong to". If you want you can construct `objB` and `objC` with `A`'s `this` pointer, but you will have to tell them explicitly that they are contained, or where to find the sibling.

Comment: Didn't think there was. Still, that's why I'm asking. I know siblings don't know about each other, so how do I call one from the other?

Comment: You could construct each with a reference to the other, or both with a reference to the parent. Alternatively you redesign and make `A` *inherit* from `B` and `C`.

Comment: This has the potential to make the classes very dependent on each other, to the point that changing one would require changing a lot of others.  In technical terms, this leads to high coupling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the cleanest way would be to "inject the dependency", that is, to pass `objC` to `methodInB`, which would then invoke `methodInC` on that object:

```
void A::methodInA()
{
    objB.methodInB(objC);
}

// ...

void B::methodInB(C &objC)
{
    objC.methodInC();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let every class B, C, D, E, etc. have a pointer to the A object of which they are subobjects.

```
class A;
class C;
class B
{
    A* pA;
    void MethodB();
};


...

void B::MethodB
{
   (pa->CObject).MethodC();
}
```